# Python retrieve video url youtube api v3

Tags: python, youtube

So, I have a python application for connecting to a chatroom and a command for retrieving youtube videos. I can't understand the v3 api system for retrieving videos at all. I found one in java but that didn't help me in any way as i'm not very good with it.

Does anybody know how I would be able to get the v3 api working with the script below? I have my developer key so that's not an issue. Thanks

```
elif used_prefix and cmd=="youtube" and len(args) > 0:
            try:
                yword=args.replace(" ","_")
                ydata= urlreq.urlopen("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&MaxResults=1&q="+yword+"key=")
                yread= str(ydata.read())
                if "<openSearch:totalResults>0</openSearch:totalResults>" in yread:
                    room.message("No results found for "+args)
                else:
                    trash , yclean=yread.split("<media:player url='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=",1)
                    yclean , trash=yclean.split("&amp;",1)
                    room.message("http://http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+yclean,True)
            except:
                room.message("Error.")
```

I already tried several options with no luck.

any help with this would be appreciated as I'm fed up with the v3 api now.

Comment: I guess you are missing the `key`? And you are missing a `&` just before `key`.

Comment: I have my key, I just didn't add it to the post. I didn't see the missing & as it's in my python script. Not sure why it's not here. Thanks for the reply.